# Sign off on a range of previous commits in git even after a push

Tags: git

How do you sign off on a range of previous commits starting from `HEAD` in git even after performing a push while retaining all other information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to achieve this by rewriting the branch. However, you'll want to limit the changes:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'cat - && echo && echo "Signed-off-by: Author <author@domain>" "$@";' HEAD~5..HEAD
```

1. `--msg-filter` changes the commit messages. It takes a command as an argument.
2. `$@` is the commit "object."
3. `HEAD~5..HEAD` is the range of commits to change.

Because you're changing history and you've already pushed to the server, you'll more likely need `git push -f` to update the changes remotely.

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more. How does `filter-branch` work to do this?

Comment: @bryankennedy How's that?

Comment: Nice! I think that really helps explain what you're doing here.

Comment: It looks like `git` now prints:
```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
         alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
         filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
         set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
```

Comment: Leave out the first `echo` to avoid a newline if you'd like you newly added line to not include an additional newline, such as when a commit already has other signed off by tags.